# Check which form fields were updated in PHP/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a form with ~20 fields to update a record. When a user submits the form, I would like to log which fields were updated (changed) in my `update_log` table along with the updated value, the username, and time. (Ex: "Andrew updated 'Supplier' to 'Acme Inc.' on November 22nd at 3:00 pm)

Previously, I've had success in instances where a single field auto-saves because as soon as the single field updates I can log it. But with a form with 20 fields, this is more difficult because I'm updating the entire form at once and do not want to log fields which didn't change.

Here's the Javascript I'm using to `POST` the update to a PHP file, which runs an update query using the `$_POST` data:

```
$("body").on('click', "#update-shipment-button", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var shipment_id= $("#update-shipment-button").attr('data-shipment-id');
    var clientName = $("#form-client-name").val();
    var poNumber = $("#form-po-number").val();
    var shipmentStatus = $("#form-shipment-status").val();
    var supplier = $("#form-supplier").val();
    var shipper = $("#form-shipper").val();
    var departureDate = $("#form-departure-date").val();
    var arrivalDate = $("#form-arrival-date").val();
    var freightForwarder = $("#form-freight-forwarder").val();
    var shippingMethod = $("#form-shipping-method").val();
    var originCountry = $("#form-origin-country").val();

    var data = {
      shipment_id: shipment_id,
      clientName: clientName,
      poNumber: poNumber,
      shipmentStatus: shipmentStatus,
      supplier: supplier,
      shipper: shipper,
      departureDate: departureDate,
      arrivalDate: arrivalDate,
      freightForwarder: freightForwarder,
      shippingMethod: shippingMethod,
      originCountry: originCountry,

    }

    // Deliver the payload!
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "st_update_shipment_query.php",
            dataType:"JSON", 
            data: data, 
            success:function(response){
              console.log("Successfully updated.");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              console.log(xhr.status);
              console.log(ajaxOptions);
              console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });

  });
```

What is the best way to approach this? Any help is appreciated :) I can clarify the question if needed.

Comment: In PHP: http://php.net/array_diff_assoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your PHP. `$arr1` contains old data (the one that you've got in your DB), and `$arr2` contains new data (in the `$_POST` var).

```
$arr1 = array(
    'fname' => 'John',
    'lname' => 'Doe'
);
$arr2 = array(
    'fname' => 'Nick',
    'lname' => 'Doe'
);
$dif = array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2);
```

Now `$dif` contains only the `key=>values` that changed.

Comment: You should check this out to gather your inputs values with JQuery instead of doing it one by one. [link](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to compare existing fields with replacing ones then enter the changed ones in a single field in a table named update_log

In your ajax script, first run a SELECT to get the present values in the database

```
$vRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE shipment_id='$shipment_id'")
```

then, foreach $_POST, compare and add changed fields in a string

```
foreach ($_POST as $vKey => $vValue)
 {$vChangedFields.= ($_POST[$vKey] != $vRow[$vKey] ? ' ' . $vKey : '');}
```

$vChangedFields now contains a list of the changed fields separated by spaces. Note that your fields in your post and in your table require to have the same names, or that won't ever compares as true